# Setting background image correctly for UITextField in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, uitextfield, xamarin, background-image

Does somebody know how to set a background image for a text field correctly? I tried it with the iOS Designer in `Xamarin` by choosing a background image and no border. But now the placeholder text as well as text typed in by the user is beginning on the same pixels. Is there a way to indent the text or how is this done correctly? The background image has the same size as the textfield.

Here is an image:

[image]

Perhaps one can only do this programmatically, but I didn't find a working solution. What about stretching on different solutions in `Xamarin`?

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the location, width and height of the text from a UITextField by using the `DrawText` method:

```
UITextField textBox = new UITextField (new RectangleF (5, 5, 50, 30));
textBox.DrawText (new RectangleF (5, 5, 45, 25));
```

Do make sure the width and height of the text doesn't exceed the width and height of the textfield. As you can see, my textfield would have a width of 50, height of 30. Experiment a bit with the x and y coordinates of the text, and make sure to subtract the x and y coordinates from the width and height of the text.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Is it allowed to call `DrawText` afterwards?

Comment: Yes. You can call this anywhere, but only after you've initialised your UITextfield

Answer (score 0):

first of all set background image in your textfield. after you add this class [Download IT](http://ge.tt/1ocd0Wq1/v/0) and add that class in your project.

Change Your margin according your requirement in `UITextField+bgImageset` class.

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {


    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 10, bounds.origin.y + 5,
                      bounds.size.width - 20, bounds.size.height - 10);
}
```

It working fine.

Comment: As I can see the solution is for Xcode in Objective-C. How would I do this in C# with Xamarin?

Comment: Sorry I have solution for Objective-C. Not for C#. because in your question there is UITextfield which is objective c. C# doen't contain UITextField.

Comment: Your right but I'm using the `MonoTouch` framework which has C# as programming language and uses the same textual notation as Apple. E.g. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/part_3_-_basic_text_input/ Thanks for your effort.